# Fat-shattering dimension

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-learning

A set of points $X = \{x\}$ is $\gamma$-shattered by a set of functions $\mathcal{F}$ if there are real numbers $r_x$ indexed by $x$ such that for any binary vector $b$ defining labeling of points from $X$ we can find a function $f \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $f(x) \geq r_x + \gamma$ if $x$ has label 1 and $f(x) \leq r_x - \gamma$ if $x$ has label -1.

In this definition, what is the role of numbers $r_x$? If we don't use $r_x$ in the definition, what will change?

Answer (score 6):

I was also looking for an explanation and this is the best one I got ([Section 4.1.2](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4471-3748-1_4)). Apparently fat-shattering is a restrictive form of P-shattering that says for some fixed $r_x$ there is some $f$ that has a margin of atleast $\gamma$.

Check out the figure in reference for clearer explanation.